# How to correctly use {if allow_comments}?

Tags: conditionals, comments, comment-form

I'm having trouble grasping the usefulness of {if allow_comments}. The comment:entries loop and comments form code are both supposed to be **outside** of channel:entries, but presumable {if allow_comments} only works **inside** channel:entries. So I find myself having to use the channel:entries tag repeatedly around the elements in order to use the conditional. So my code get's all ugly like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" status="Open|Featured" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}    
{if allow_comments && comment_total > 0}
                <div class="dividerBig">.</div>
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <ul class="comments">
                {/if}<!-- end allow comments -->
            {/exp:channel:entries}

                    {exp:comment:entries channel="blog" url_title="{segment_3}" orderby="date" sort="asc"}
                    <li>
                        <h3><span>{name}</span></h3>
                        {comment}
                        <span class="date">{comment_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</span>
                    </li>
                    {/exp:comment:entries}

            {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" status="Open|Featured" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
                {if allow_comments && comment_total > 0}    
                </ul>
                {/if}<!-- end allow comments -->

                {if allow_comments}
                <div class="dividerBig">.</div>
                <h1>Write a comment</h1>
                {/if}<!-- end allow comments -->
            {/exp:channel:entries}

                {exp:comment:form channel="blog" url_title="{segment_3}" preview="blog/comment" form_class="default" return="{homepage}blog/comment-thanks"}
```

Etc...

This looks rediculous and I'm sure using so many channel:entries tags is a performance hit, but how else do you effectively use the {if allow_comments} conditional?

Do people put their comment:entries and comments forms inside embed templates? Is that any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like this, within my Channel Entries tag:

```
{if comment_total > "0" || allow_comments}
    {embed="blog/_comment_list"}
{/if}

{if allow_comments}
    {embed="blog/_comment_add"}
{if:else}
    <p>Sorry, comments are closed.</p>
{/if}
```

With the appropriate chunks of `comment:entries` and `comment:form` code in those embeds respectively. Much cleaner.

Comment: Agree that's much cleaner. Do you know what the performance difference is of using embeds vs. having the comments and form in the same template?

Comment: I don't have measurements to that effect, but on a single entry template it will be minor.